# Ember DS.model exposed data attributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm attempting to implement [Ember Crossfilter](https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberCrossfilter) and am having some mild success and I think part of my pain is due to some data attributes not being exposed.

When extending `Ember.Object` like so:

```
App.Cat = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null,
  cuteness: null
})
```

and creating objects I can see within my Chrome console that they look something like this:

```
__ecBitwiseColour: 3
__ecBitwiseCountry: 2
__ember1389472009050: undefined
__ember1389472009050_meta: Meta
_super: undefined
cuteness: 5
get cuteness: function () {
set cuteness: function (value) {
id: 2
name: 'Boris'
get name: function () {
set name: function (value) {
__proto__: Object
```

but if I implement this by extending DS.Model

```
App.Cat = DS.Model.extend({
  name: null,
  cuteness: null
})
```

my Chrome console is more like this.

```
__ecBitwiseColour: 3
__ecBitwiseCountry: 2
__ember1389472306613: "ember330"
__ember1389472306613_meta: Meta
_attributes: Object
_changesToSync: Object
_data: Object
_deferredTriggers: Array[0]
_inFlightAttributes: Object
_recordArrays: Ember.OrderedSet
_relationships: Object
_super: undefined
_suspendedRelationships: false
age: undefined
get age: function () {
set age: function (value) {
container: Container
currentState: (...)
get currentState: function () {
set currentState: function (value) {
data: (...)
errors: Class
id: "2"
name: undefined
get name: function () {
set name: function (value) {
store: Class
toString: function () { return ret; }
__proto__: Object
```

All my data is under the `_data` attribute, but as part of this object like when its extended from `Ember.Object`.

My question is, why is this happening, and is there anyway around this so I can use my `DS.models` with `EmberCrossfilter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, attributes are stored in three places in Ember Data `_data` (saved data), `_attributes` (dirty attribute values), `_inFlightAttributes` (values that are being saved and about to be applied to `_data`).

This is why you should always use a getter, if you fail to do so you may be looking at incorrect data.  The getter will query `_attributes`, `_inFlightAttributes`, then `_data` in that order.

The reason it's implemented like so is for the purpose of dirty property checking, rollback ability etc.

Now EmberCrossFilter is cheating by not using the getter, unfortunately this is a major no no in Ember world.  Computed properties wouldn't work, in fact this will really only work for POJOs and objects with the property (not computed) right on the object.

I'd probably fork/PR and switch all of the direct references to getters

```
   // Initialise the sorting using Crossfilter's `quicksort`.
    var sortAlgorithm   = crossfilter.quicksort.by(function(d) { return d[property]; });
```

to

```
    // Initialise the sorting using Crossfilter's `quicksort`.
    var sortAlgorithm   = crossfilter.quicksort.by(function(d) { return Em.get(d,property); });
```

etc

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I was afraid it might be something like that!  It looks like I have some work to do.

Comment: Actually, this isn't going be as hard as I thought.  What is the difference between doing: `Em.get(d, property)` and `d.get(property)`?

Comment: if the object isn't an ember object the get method isn't attached to it (IE a POJO you can't call `pojo.get()`), but if you're just working with Ember Data records and objects that extend Ember.Object you're fine using `obj.get`